# dynamicEDTOctomap.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, octomap, collision-detection, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed dynamicedt3d library using sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-dynamicedt3d
Included in my CMakeLists as:

> set(DYNAMICEDT3D_LIBRARIES "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libdynamicedt3d.so")
> include_directories( ${DYNAMICEDT3D_LIBRARIES} )
> > add_executable(get_occupancy src/get_occupancy.cpp)
> > target_link_libraries(get_occupancy $(DYNAMICEDT3D_LIBRARIES))

But while doing a catkin_make, I still get the error fatal error: dynamicEDTOctomap.h: No such file or directory
#include <dynamicEDTOctomap.h>

Can somebody help me figure this out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255824/dynamicedtoctomap.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you did was to declare your library file to be the include directory. This is clear whythis fails...

To quote from the `dynamicEDT3DConfig.cmake`:

> ```
> #  Usage from an external project:
> #    In your CMakeLists.txt, add these lines:
> #
> #    FIND_PACKAGE(dynamicedt3d REQUIRED )
> #    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${DYNAMICEDT3D_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> >     #    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MY_TARGET_NAME
> >     ${DYNAMICEDT3D_LIBRARIES})
> ```

You should probably also add `dynamic-edt-3d` as a `depend` to your `package.xml`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) on 2017-07-25**:
I was following a tutorial given here http://wiki.ros.org/mallasrikanth/octomap
But I think that is for an older version and the issue is solved now that I went back to simply finding package and including directories. Thanks!